# Difference in 2D array initialization

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

Here's a snippet that I am finding puzzling. Why is that `y[0][0] = 2` initializing all the columns in all rows?

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = []
>>> x.append([0])
>>> x.append([0])
>>> x.append([0])
>>> x.append([0])
>>> x
[[0], [0], [0], [0]]
>>> y = [ [0] * 1 ] * 4
>>> y
[[0], [0], [0], [0]]
>>> x == y
True
>>> x[0][0] = 2
>>> y[0][0] = 2
>>> x
[[2], [0], [0], [0]]
>>> y
[[2], [2], [2], [2]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the line `y = [ [0] * 1 ] * 4` what the Python interpreter is actually doing is creating a list that has 4 pointers to the same object. You are actually creating one list `[0]` and 4 references to the same list. When you alter one of them, you alter all of them.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with how you're initializing `y`:

```
y = [ [0] * 1 ] * 4
```

This basically says 'create a list with a single element, `0`'. Then it says 'put that list four times into a new list'. Thus, if you change the original list, you change all the subsequent copies (references, really) you made, since they each point to the same piece of memory.